# Laravel - only a zero is saved to the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple car model with one attribute:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

/*
*   TODO:
*   Property Fotos ausfüllen
*/

class Car extends Model
{
    //Tablenname
    protected $table = 'cars';

    protected $fillable = ['title'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
    *   @var string
    */
    protected $title = NULL;

    /**
    *   @var integer
    */
    protected $imagesId = NULL;

    /**
    *
    *   @return string
    */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->attributes['title'];
    }


    /**
    *
    *   @param string $title
    *
    *   @return void
    */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->attributes['title'] = $title;
    }

}
```

This is my store function from the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Car;


class CarController extends Controller
{

 /**
  * Store a newly created resource in storage.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
  public function store(Request $request)
  {     
      $car = new Car();

      // $car->setTitle($request->title);
      $car->setTitle('stackoverflow');
      $car->save();

      ...
   }
}
```

However, this is how the entry in the database looks like:

[image]

Title is always zero! I also tried it with other models, same.

Comment: what is your field data type?

Comment: whoops. It is `int` instead of `varchar`. Now it works after I changed it! Thanks! Please create an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check field datatype.if you want to store string you have to change your 'title' field datatype to varchar.
hope it works.